# Webpack связи между бандлами

Tags: webpack, webpack2

Реально ли организовать связь между бандлами?

например я создаю

**common.js** - это бандл

```
const modal = new Modal();
```

**another.js** - это другой бандл, в котором я хочу

```
modal.open()
```

До вебпака была глобальная область видимости и я мог в another.js  прописать этот код, при условии правильного подключения файлов на странице

```
<script src="common.js"></script>
<script src="another.js"></script>
```

сейчас каждый бандл имеет свою область видимость и чтобы прокинуть одну переменную из одного бандла в другой приходиться очень сильно извращаться

Comment: Извращаться не нужно, нужно `import`ировать один файл в другой перед его использованием. Для данной задачи также можно использовать `RequireJS`

Comment: что конкрретно и куда импортировать?

Answer (score 0):

Скорее вопрос в организации правиьльной архитектуры приложения, которая позволила бы не зависеть от глобальных переменных, тем не менее, можете повесить глобальные переменные на window

```
window.myNamespace = window.myNamespace || {};
window.myNamespace.modal = new Modal();
```